# What's the rails way to include a field in a join model when listing an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, has-many-through

So if I have the following relationship

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_user_relationships
   has_many :users, :through => :item_user_relationships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_user_relationships
   has_many :items, :through => :item_user_relationships
end

class ItemUserRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   belongs_to :user

   attr_accessible :role
end
```

What's the rails way to include the `role` attribute when listing all the Users of an Item?

```
@users = @item.users # I want to include the role as part of a user
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I'm still having trouble with this. My goal is to get an array of User models that have their role included in the attributes.

Comment: What I ended up doing was `@users = @item.users.all(:joins => :item_user_relationships, :select => "users.*, item_user_relationships.role")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if I understand you correctly, but maybe this is what you want?

```
@users = @item.users
@users.each do |user|
  puts user.item_user_relationships.first.role
end
```